# Use bitwise operator / bit manipulation to decompose a decimal into powers of two. So if we have 9 = 2^0 + 2^3

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(bitsSet(14));
}

public static BitSet bitSet(long num) {
    BitSet bitSet = new BitSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        if (((num >>> i) & 1) != 0) {
            bitSet.set(i);
        }
    }
    return bitSet;
}
```

I tried this code above but my bitSet.set gives errors and i am not sure if my approach is right at all

Comment: You should probably tell us what error you got.

Answer (score 1):

Your method name and the call name aren't the same.

```
System.out.println(bitsSet(14));
```

whereas your method decleration has.

```
public static BitSet bitSet(long num) 
{
...
}
```

---

Also I suggest you to use a different name for variables and functions.

```
public static BitSet bitSet(long num) 
{
BitSet myBitSet = new BitSet();
...
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I just wrote it wrong. That is not my error.